# How do I add the current date before the file extension for multiple files in a directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, rename

How do I add the current date before the file extension for multiple files in a directory?

Original files:

```
Expenses.log
Allowances.log
```

Output:

```
Expenses_20170624.log
Allowances_20170624.log
```

This command appends the date after the file extension. :(

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file}_$(date +"%d%m%Y")"; done
```

Answer (score 6):

Use parameter expansion to separate the extension:

```
#! /bin/bash
date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
for file in * ; do
    basename=${file%.*}    # Remove extension
    extension=${file##*.}  # Remove basename
    mv "$file" "$basename"_"$date.$extension"
done
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work well if the filename includes a dot, e.g. "file.1.txt", then the basename would be "file" instead of "file.1"

Comment: @Vasilis: Have you tried it? It works correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

With short **`rename`** command (*Perl* implementation):

```
rename 's/\.([^.]+)$/_'$(date +"%d%m%Y")'.$1/' *
```