# add date to existing filenames

Tags: shell-script, rename, date

I have multiple files at various locations in my home directory.

```
abc1.txt abc432.txt abc3123.txt abc.txt abc988822.txt
```

I want to add date to these filename without changing the original names. Result should be like below:

```
abc1-120917.txt abc432-120917.txt abc3123-120917.txt abc-120917.txt abc988822-120917.txt
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want *copies* of the files with the date appended? I don't see how you could rename files "without changing the original names".  Or do you mean "without changing the first part of the file name; just append the date" ?

Comment: By "various locations in my home directory" do you mean that they could be in sub-directories as well?  What's the pattern of filenames that you want to rename like this? "Starts with `abc`"?

Comment: Are you always adding the same date (120917), or today's date? Or some timestamp feature of the file?

Comment: What date is that? Is that 2012-09-17?

Comment: or `12-09-2017` ? The question really should be extended/elaborated

Comment: Very related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373158/how-do-i-add-the-current-date-before-the-file-extension-for-multiple-files-in-a

Comment: Do you want to rename every `.txt` file, only those that match a patterm? Which pattern? `abc*.txt`, `abc<decimals>.txt`, `*<decimal>.txt`, `<alphas><decimal>.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention if you want a fixed date or now(), so here's one with a fixed date:

`for i in * ; do echo mv "${i}" "${i%.*}-120917.${i##*.}"; done`

And here's now with a dynamic date (following your format of dmy):

`for i in * ; do echo mv "${i}" "${i%.*}-$(date +%d%m%y).${i##*.}"; done`

If satisfied with the result, remove the `echo` from the oneliner.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to add two dashes after the mv to prevent unintended option parsing on files that start with a dash.

Comment: @JeffSchaller OK, didn't understand properly how does work blob. I trust your opinion on that